# Tensorflow Serving Client Script Hangs At stub.predict.future()

Tags: tensorflow, flask, mod-wsgi, grpc, tensorflow-serving

This is my first time asking a question here so I will try to be descriptive. I am relatively new to python and tensorflow, and have been learning it specifically for a project.

I am currently working to deploy a tensorflow model using tensorflow serving and flask with wsgi. I have been following this architecture: https://github.com/Vetal1977/tf_serving_flask_app

I am running `tensorflow_model_server` on `port=9000`.

I know that `tensorflow_model_server` is working, because when I execute the `tensorflow_serving_client.py` from command line, I get the expected response. I have tested this command line execution on every user account.

Similarly, I know that Flask + WSGI is working, because I can see `log.info` points dropping into the apache error log as it works its way through the script. If I return something before it gets to the line in question, it works just fine.

However, when the application is executed with Flask + WSGI, it hangs at [this line](https://github.com/Vetal1977/tf_serving_flask_app/blob/master/api/gan/logic/tf_serving_client.py#L70): `result = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)  # 5 seconds` (https://github.com/Vetal1977/tf_serving_flask_app/blob/master/api/gan/logic/tf_serving_client.py#L70)

I can see that it hangs as I monitor `top` and `tail -f error.log` and see the same apache process sit there until it is killed or apache is restarted.

I am really stuck on the fact that it works when executed via command line, but not when Flask + WSGI runs it. Can anyone provide suggestions or point me in the right direction? Am I headed down the right path with this? Any assistance at all would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have uploaded the minimal code to a github repo here: https://github.com/raymondtri/client-test along with a minimal setup that does require flask, wsgi, tensorflow, and tensorflow-serving.

Thanks in advance,

Ray

Comment: Maybe it is slower with Flask + WSGI, did you try increasing it to more than 5 seconds? Try 30.0 instead of 5.0

Comment: Yes I tried increasing the time.

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable - done, this has been updated to include a link to a public github repo that contains minimal code

Comment: How have you configured mod_wsgi? Are you using daemon mode? Have you forced mod_wsgi to run your application in the main Python interpreter context? See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api about configuration that avoids some Python packages hanging.

Comment: Experiencing he same issue but with gunicorn + eventlet.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and many hours, I think that this has something to do with how mod_wsgi forks processes, and how grpc has some known issues with that. I have a feeling that things are getting orphaned as the process is forked and that is what is causing the script to hang.

I could be wrong though, that is just my current hypothesis.